# Possible race condition in this java code?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

```
class Employee {
   transient Department = new Department();
}
```

```
class Department {
   boolean isClosed;
}
```

by default `isClosed` is false, some point in my logic its changed to `true` (`Department.isClosed = true`) but later in process its changed back to `false` ==> No logic to explicitly change this.

Based on my understanding, I suspect that this is happening due to Race Condition where different thread have modified this flag or one thread is not getting updated view of data.

Is there anyway to prove this understanding? or possibly any other suspects?

Please note, Its difficult(total 8-10 hours of retry and processing) to reproduce this issue as we face on production very rarely.

Comment: "later in process" <-- how "later" is "later"?

Comment: Do you ever set it to a new (other) Department?

Comment: I don't think the variable can be changed to the previous value. If anything, I'd expect that you're still seeing the original value, before the change. Do you see the `false` in the thread that turned it to `true` earlier on? Or you have multiple instances of `Department` and the other one has the initial value.

Comment: Have you tried to make isClosed volatile ? to ensure that "one thread is not getting updated view of data." does not happen?

Comment: @Sweeper in about 150ms.

Comment: @dreamcrash I am planning to do that once I have someway to confirm its just problem of stale data view. I am also considering using Boolean.

Comment: @VedantKekan You might as well use AtomicBoolean then

Comment: The simple answer is: unless you are taking steps to ensure the writes of `isClosed` [happen before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) subsequent reads, there is a data race in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `isClosed` volatile if it is modified and then accessed from different threads. In the other case, a different thread may see a stale value even after seeing a more up-to-date value.